# How to calibrate a superdrive's laser for CD and DVD burning?

Tags: optical-drive, cd-burning

Since I bought my Macbook Pro 5.1 two and a half years ago I could barely burn DVDs and CDs. I have read some discussions on the Apple forums that pointed a potential solution that didn't work for me: blowing compressed air into the superdrive.

The only thing that actually worked for me was to go to the nearest Apple reseller and ask them to run a special calibration DVD on my Mac. After that I can burn CDs and DVDs for a few months, but then again I have to go back to the Apple reseller (which is now closed) and ask them to recalibrate my superdrive laser.

Is there any other way of calibrating my superdrive's laser for CD and DVD burning?

Comment: I've seen "cleaning disks"  for sale that are like a CD with TINY bristles that are meant to clean the lens of the laser, maybe that's what they were using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no calibration procedure. Perhaps they cleaned the inside of the mac to reduce dust, but the superdrive units are replaced as a whole by Apple technicians - you get a new drive - not something that is "tuned up".

The only calibration DVD are for running reference sound or visual patterns to help you calibrate a display system for video to ensure dim grey are differentiated visually from black, to focus a projection system, or to check channels or sound levels on an audio system.

Of course there are many cleaning DVD on the market, but I would be loathe to subject my SuperDrive slot loading mechanism to one of those. It could easily get stuck and do far more damage to the drive.